# Reverse engineering MQTT payload in a (apparently) sophisticated smart lamp

Tags: networking, smart-devices

## Background

I have recently bought a (quite expensive) smart lamp. It is not from a known producer, it's a relatively small company, but they seem to have implemented MQTT in a quite serious way.

## Initial analysis

Through packet inspection, I have extracted the following relevant MQTT messages exchanged between the lamp and the server.

- Authentication: the password is hashed, but the username is clear: let's say it is `123456789012&randString` (yes, the username is comprised of my account number and an apparently random string)
- MQTT broker address: let's say it is `randString.server.inchina.com` (the randString matches the one in the username)
- Payload of lamp turn on, off, change color, change brightness, etc.
- MQTT topic: let's say it is `/randString/123456789012/user/devices/pese/sub` (randString matches the one in the username and the 12 chars number is my account number)

## First approach to the problem

What I did is the following, in order to communicate with the lamp via MQTT:

- Set up my mqtt broker at `my.mqtt.broker`
- Added a `dnsmasq` rule on my openWRT router so that all traffic to `randString.server.inchina.com` is redirected to `my.mqtt.broker`
- Wrote a `mosquitto` `auth_plugin` in C that allows clients to authenticate with `username123` only, but can use any password (yeah very safe)

## Testing the set-up

I have tested everything and, if I send (certain) payloads to the lamp, it answers (sometimes with an error message if the message contains weird values).

Now, I have tried to send the exact payload I have sniffed to turn on and off the lamp, it answers by sending its status (like RSSI etc.) but nothing happens.

Here is the payload I have sniffed when I turn on the light (username and topic are redacted, if they will be necessary I'll post a pastebin link so that I can later delete it and spread information as little as possible as it contains my username).

```
{"id":49,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"SetOrControlDevices","params":{"data":[{"data":{"dps":{"1":true},"time":{"1":2}},"node_id":17,"sn":33333}],"frame_status":0,"from_account":"123456789012","md5":"F8CC42572A96E337034CB982282C91BA","rand":"D8SN8R6J","time":"1702424815396"}}
```

## The problem

After a quick research, I have realized that the fields `md5` and `rand` are not there for pure aesthetic purposes. They are evidence of an implementation of MQTT enhanced authentication through DIGEST-MD5. It is an authentication method that uses the MD5 hash and a challenge-response mechanism to secure communication between client and server. This method avoids transmitting passwords in plain text over the network. When a client wants access, the server sends a challenge, and the client responds with a hashed result. If the server's expected result matches the client's response, authentication succeeds, enhancing security against password exposure and replay attacks.

## The question

Now here is my question: how can I approach (and possibly "hack") this novel type of MQTT authentication?

## Other options to consider

I have considered other options such as:

- Reverse engineering the firmware: however, it uses a very very peculiar Chinese (not exported it seems) microchip, not a classic (still Chinese) ESP32 nor ESP8266 et similia.
- "Decrypting" (is this the right word?) the hashed password: however, these people clearly know what they are doing and it is not a commonly known password. On top of that it would violate T&Cs and would probably configure some sort of crime that I don't want to commit.
- Brute for... ehmm never mind. Not an option.
- MITM attack? Isn't what I have already tried a MITM? Are there other ways?

Comment: Is there a companion app to control the lamp? If so that might reveal more information.

Comment: There is for iOS and Android. I decompiled the one for android, but I found nothing concerning MQTT. The device comes with a touch screen that controls the light via BLE and updates its firmware via WiFi. I downloaded a .bin file and a .img file when updating its firmware but I have no idea on where to start reverse engineering those.

Comment: The firmware files can be a place to start. Run binwalk and see if it is able to extract or find anything interesting.